# How to unblock IP Address that is blocked by hosting server?

Tags: networking, ip, hosting, cpanel, blocking

I have a website that runs on a hosting. However, I suspect that one of my website files has been infected by virus which causes IP address blocking when this IP address visits my website. The real problem is my department internet has ever accessed my virus-infected website so the IP eventually blocked (all internet connection in my department are the same, it is static IP). So, the IP address no longer can visit the website since it is blocked.

How to unblock this IP Address? Can I do it on my website's cPanel? I have also deleted all files on my hosting.

Thank you very much for the answer. I'd really appreciate all of the answers!

Comment: You should ask your hosting to delete the IP because it has been listed on their firewall

Comment: I have contacted them, and now I can visit my webpage again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are a shared hosting environment. 
You will need to contact your hosting service provider and they will be able to unblock the IPs from the firewall.

And if its a dedicated server where your website is hosted then , then you can simply remove the IP from CSF using the command csf -dr IPAddress

Comment: Yes, I have contacted my hosting service provider. Now, I've got my IP address unblocked. Thanks.